# How to use react context API in next.js app for authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I want to do react app on next.js app.
I want do this on next.js app. But I don't have any current idea. Please help me to solve this.
I use user authentication on backend `node.js + passport.js + passport-local-mongoose + express.session`. On react app use `context API` for store user data.

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Spin, message } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER;
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const getUser = async () => {
      const endPoint = `${url}/v1/users/auth`;
      await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: endPoint,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          const { data } = res;
          setUser(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {})
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    };
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {loading ? (
        <div className='tmtube-global flexCenter'>
          <Spin size='large' />
        </div>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update

### Using NextAuth.js with a Custom Provider and Custom Database

NextAuth.js allows you to create custom authentication providers and use a custom database to store user data. Just make sure you are doing all these steps.

- **install NextAuth.js:**
  `npm install next-auth`
- **Create a Custom Provider:**
  Create a custom authentication provider with app (next.js 13) at this directory `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`.

and this file should be like this:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Credentials({
      // The name to display on the sign-in form (e.g., "Sign in with...")
      name: 'Custom Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: {  label: "Password",  type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        // Your custom authentication logic here
        // You can query your user data directly to db here. It is safe.
        const user = { id: 1, name: "John Doe" }; // Replace with your user data logic

        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          // if user not found or logic not accepted.
          return null
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin', // your custom page
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session(session, token) {
      // if you need to add more info in session
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.name = token.name;
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

- **Usage in Your Application:**

You can now use your custom authentication provider in your Next.js components. Here's an example of a login form:

```
// app/auth/signin.js (this our page)
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react' // login the user

export default function SignIn() {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    const credentials = {
      username: formData.get('username'),
      password: formData.get('password'),
    };

    const result = await signIn('credentials', { ...credentials, redirect: false });

    if (!result.error) {
      // Successfully logged in
      // Redirect or perform any necessary actions
    } else {
      // Handle authentication error
      console.error(result.error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

- **Finally If you wanna get user data you can simply:**

```
// any component file
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function Component({}) {
  const { status, data } = useSession()
  return (
    <div>
      {status === 'loading' ? (
        <>Loading ...</>
      ) : status === 'unauthenticated' ? (
        <>No User Logged In</>
      ) : (
        <span>
          There is authenticated user <br />
          {data?.user.username}
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### That is it. Let me know if you need more help. Happy Coding!

Comment: I am try use it but cannot do. How to do this using this?

Comment: or how to config next auth provider with auth via backend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).